# Is there a detailed analysis comparing Jonah's story in the Bible with the Sun and the seasons?

Tags: mythohistory, bible, interpretation, metaphors

In [this video](https://youtu.be/MOgA25ZE9kw) Derek of Myth vision explores the story of Jonah and the Fish swallowing him.

There is this comment below in that video.

[image: image of comment text]

This seems like a very interesting allegory of nature. Has some scholar of Bible interpreted in this way?

Comment: It's an interesting allegory for nature...if the Bible were written further north. But it makes no sense when looked at in its context. Also, mourning doves, that fly south for the winter, are from North America. This sort of mythological "explanation" is just crackpot hypothesizing.

Comment: @cmw It was very popular in the 19th century to treat any story at all as a solar myth.  Infamously, a writer was able to prove, by the standards of evidence that they used, that Napoleon Bonaparte was a solar myth.

Comment: @Mary Oh, yes, I'm very familiar with the trend. It was shortly replaced by the "dying and rising gods" super-lens. I thought we had all moved past that in the last...hundred something years!